# подключение js в файл

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Хочу потестировать google api. Создал сразу три файла: `index1.html`, `main.css`, `main.js`

Подключаю все-все сразу в один html 
(фрагмент)

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

После хочу раскинуть по файлам. js скидываю в файл `main.js` (удаляю js в html и на месте кода подключаю линку). Тестирую - все работает.

Далее копирую аpi и сую в новый файл `googl-api.js` файл все работает(ниже структура)

```
<script src="googl-api.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

А теперь фокус-покус - вырезаю содержимое файла `main.js` и вставляю в конец  файла `googl-api.js` и не работает!  Что за чушь? Меня в принципе устраивает, что работает в разных файлах, но не могу разобраться в чем подвох? Вроде оно так и так должно работать!

---

**UPD**

Ошибка, которую выдает в консоли браузера:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addDomListener' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина неработоспособности собранного js в файле https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp. Он внутри себя подгружает функционал google api (файл https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/7/intl/ru_ALL/main.js) нехитрой командой

```
document.write('<' + 'script src="' + src + '"><' + '/script>');
```

А ваш код выполняется раньше, то есть когда функционал еще не загружен.

Answer (score 0):

Используй:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp?callback=initialize"></script>`

Дополнительная информация есть [тут](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API).

Comment: ну вопрос был чуть другой: почему я не могу все засунуть в один файл? (мне дробить и дополнительные линки не желательно использовать); А по отдельности работает - вопросу нет. А в "куче" не работает((